# different contravariance requirement for map & flatmap

Tags: scala

Why map funciton is correct but flatmap is wrong? The only difference is that map has a parameter of (f:A=>B) while flatmap has a parameter of (f: A=>Either[E,B]), the compiler complain E is a contravariance position. Since f:A=>B is also a parameter, why compiler doen't complain A is a contravariance position. Both of map, flatmap need a parameter, I remember a parameter is a contravariance position, I just doens't understand why map works while flatmap not.

```
object test {
  import scala.{Option=>_,Either=>_,_}
  sealed trait Either[+E,+A]{
    def map[B](f:A=>B):Either[E,B]= this match {
      case Left(e)=>Left(e)
      case Right(a)=>Right(f(a))
    }

   def flatMap[B](f: A=>Either[E,B]):Either[E,B] = this match {
      case Left(e)=>Left(e)
      case Right(a)=>f(a)
    }      

  }
  case class Right[+A](a:A) extends Either[Nothing,A]
  case class Left[+E](e:E) extends Either[E,Nothing]

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A=>B` has type `Function[-A,+B]`

So for all functions, the arguments are contravariant, and the return types are covariant. So we can do the following:

```
N extends M
Y extends X

val a : M=>Y = ...
val b : N=>X = a

val x:X = b(new N)
```

But what about when we nest our functions.

```
(A=>B)=>(C=>D)
```

Now `A=>B` is in a contravariant position, and `A` is in a contrvariant position within a contravariant position. What does this mean? Before it meant where ever `A` was expected we could use a supertype of `A` instead. In our example, we had a function taking `N` as a parameter, but we gave it a function taking `M`, the super type of `N`.

Lets try it with our Function=>Function

```
def f(g: (M=>Y)=>(N=>X)) {...}

val x:(N=>X)=>(M=>Y) = ...

f(x) // this works
```

So something in a contravariant position we can give a supertype. But in a contra-contra-variant position we can use a subtype. So contra-contra-variance is equal to covariance.

---

In your example `map` you use a covariant type `A` in a contra-contra-variant position, so that becomes covariant, so that compiles okay.

In `flatMap` you use `A` the same way, but `B` which is covariant is used in a contravariant position. This is what is wrong.

To solve this use:

```
def flatMap[F>:E,B](f:A=>Either[F,B]):Either[F,B]
```